# Добавить index.php к url в htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

На сайте(WordPress) нужно добавить к URL index.php/, подскажите как сделать?

**Сейчас:**

```
mysite.com
mysite.com/category/post
mysite.com/page
```

**Нужно**

```
mysite.com
mysite.com/index.php/category/post
mysite.com/index.php/page
```

Сейчаc htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: А можно спросить -  зачем? WordPress и без этого работает.

Comment: Присоединяюсь к вопросу. Зачем?

Comment: Переношу сайт с джумлы на вордпрес, и там везде в урлах добавлялась index.php/ после корня сайта

Comment: А в WordPress не добавляется. Вам-то зачем, чтобы лишние буквы были в url?

Comment: Хочется что бы все url сохранились после переезда

Comment: Не майся фигнёй. Наоборот пропиши 301й с дебелиззма  `index.php/` на нормальные урлы. ПСы переиндексят быстро (если сайт нормальный и без др ошибок)

Answer (score 0):

Лучшим советом, как уже писали в комментариях, сделать нормальные URL и поставить на них 301 редирект. Но если отвечать на поставленный вопрос, то не пойму в чем сложность, т.к. настройки ссылок легко меняются через админку:

**Настройки > Постоянные ссылки > Общие настройки**

Выбираем пункт произвольно и пишем, в данном случае, такой вариант:

```
/index.php/%category%/%postname%/
```

Если в ссылках помимо названия категории будет слово **category**, которое, скорее всего не нужно, то достаточно установить плагин для удаления этого названия. Например, плагин "WP Remove Category Base".